# Notification icon missing on Apple Watch in iOS 11

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-watch

Notifications coming from our app in iOS 11 are missing the app's icon when they appear on the Apple Watch.

We have the iPhone Notification iOS 7-11 icons in our AppIcon asset, as well as iPad Notifications iOS 7-11, and all of the pertinent spotlight, settings, and app icons for various devices for iOS 7-11.

Any ideas as to what we might be missing? This was working fine in iOS 10 and it stopped working in iOS 11.

Comment: Finally I've been able to find something about this on google. I am experiencing the same thing but its for all Twitter notifications. If I pull the notification shade down, the icon is there but when receiving the notification only the default "icon wireframe" shows up and no icon. I'm curious to see what the issue is. I am going to assume something in WatchOS 4 / iOS 11 is not rendering the icon "fast enough".

Comment: I am having the same Issue with Twitter and a bunch other apps on my Series 1 Apple Watch.

Comment: Also having this exact issue - Apple watch series 3, iOS 11. 

Seems to be Snapchat and Facebook missing for me!

Comment: Fixed in 4.1 Beta 2. Now appicons will be shown correctly on Watch again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Skyborg pointed out, this appears to be a watchOS bug and is fixed in watchOS 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Go to AppIcon asset, on the right side, you'll probably see:

[image]

Change it, say, to *watchOS 2.0 and Later*. And you will see that asset is now extended with icons for Apple Watch:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem – we've added all the watch icons and it's still not showing up when notifications are received on the watch.

Comment: Its a Problem with XCode 9 and Upload. I filled a radar and got the answer that its a known issue. 

Some Tips are here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88676

Answer (score 0):

Upload with Application loader in the latest 8 Version of Xcode did the Trick for me. Apple Watch Icons are now on the watch again.

Comment: Fixed in 4.1 Beta 2. Now appicons will be shown correctly on Watch again.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fixed in iOS 11.1 according to apple

> **Other improvements and fixes**
>
> Fixes an issue where app icons were not appearing in notifications on
> Apple Watch

iOS11.1 changelog: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208067